# Adding GPS coordinate points to point feature class using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: attribute-table, coordinates, gps, arcgis-pro, feature-class

I have a raster, and in ArcGIS Pro 2.4, I created a point shapefile with 830 points. I forgot to specify that I wanted to show the GPS points in the attributes table of each point. However, I need to add the GPS coordinates as another field.

How can I do this without creating another point layer and creating all those points again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Add XY Coordinates" tool is what you need. It adds the XY coordinates from the spatial projection that you are working with to your point feature class.